# 240. Search a 2D Matrix II

Tags: javascript, data-structures

https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix-ii/description/

> Write an efficient algorithm that searches for a value target in an m
> x n integer matrix matrix. This matrix has the following properties:
>
> Integers in each row are sorted in ascending from left to right.
> Integers in each column are sorted in ascending from top to bottom.
>
> Input: matrix = [[1,4,7,11,15],[2,5,8,12,19],[3,6,9,16,22],[10,13,14,17,24],[18,21,23,26,30]],

> target = 5 Output: true

I checked youtube videos on how to do it and before watching youtube video, i tried to do myself.

My understanding is that to find some place in grid or graph, BFS is the fastest way to do.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * @param {number[][]} matrix
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var searchMatrix = function(matrix, target) {
    if(matrix[0][0]>target){
        return false
    }
    const rows = matrix.length
    const cols = matrix[0].length
    const visited = Array(rows).fill(null).map((element)=> Array(cols).fill(false))
    let queue = []
    queue.push([0,0])
    while(queue.length>0){
        let [x, y] = queue.shift()
        visited[y][x] = true
        if(matrix[y][x] == target){
            return true
        }
        let direction
        if(matrix[y][x]>target){
            direction = [[x-1, y], [x, y-1]]
        }
        else{
            direction = [[x+1,y],[x, y+1]]
        }
        for(let i=0, _length = direction.length; i<_length; i++){
            if(direction[i][1]>=0 && direction[i][1] >=0 && direction[i][0]<=(cols-1) && direction[i][1]<=(rows-1)){
                if(!visited[direction[i][1]][direction[i][0]]){
                    queue.push(direction[i])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
};
```

I am dividing my node traversal to less than usual, I don't know how much is this.

I am getting a time Limit exceeded error with 60/130 passed

Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong here if there is no way BFS can do this, why is BFS not good at this? I mean in a general sense so that I can use that knowledge in further problems.

I am

Comment: I suspect a binary search on each row should be pretty fast, and you can do a pre-test to see if the target is out of range (smaller than the first entry or larger than the last).

Comment: i saw in yt video saying that binary search can be fast but i am learning BFS so i wanted to learn how can i solve this with BFS

Comment: BFS is not going to take any advantage of the fact that the rows and columns are sorted. (I'd do rows because the values will be closer together in memory.)

Comment: Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: i thought that i am taking two child based on the target value and the value of matrix at that position, is that not taking advantage of the sorted data? I am sorry, i am making sure if i am thinking right

Answer (score 1):

One efficient algorithm to search for a value in this type of matrix is to start at the top-right corner of the matrix and compare the value at that position to the target. If the value at the top-right corner is greater than the target, move left one column. If the value at the top-right corner is less than the target, move down one row. Repeat this process until the target is found or the search reaches the bottom-left corner of the matrix.

Here's some pseudocode for this algorithm:

```js
function search(matrix, target) {
    let row = 0;
    let col = matrix[0].length - 1;
    while (row < matrix.length && col >= 0) {
        if (matrix[row][col] === target) {
            return true;
        } else if (matrix[row][col] > target) {
            col--;
        } else {
            row++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This algorithm has a time complexity of O(m + n), where m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns in the matrix. This is because the algorithm will move left or down at most m + n times before reaching the bottom-left corner of the matrix.

The above algorithm can be used for the given input matrix and the target value of 5 and the algorithm will return True as 5 is present in the matrix.

Comment: this is a really good approach.